# how to fix this compiler error which related to boost and VS conflicting definition for xtime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I am trying to write a set of code and I am getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\chrono(736): error C2872: 'xtime' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\thr/xtimec.h(23) : xtime'
1>          or       'C:\Local\boost\boost/thread/xtime.hpp(35) : boost::xtime'
```

How can I fix it?

I am using VS 2013

Comment: Do you have`using namespace boost` anywhere in your code by any chance?

Comment: @n.m. : No, I checked and I don't have it. it was the first things that came to my mind, but I don't have it!

Comment: As this error is in include files which is of VS and it might be invoked from some place. Can you provide full error log ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using namespace boost at global so because of that compiler is seeing two symbol.

To avoid this kind of error use namespace boost explicitly like `boost::xtime`

Comment: I don't have it anywhere. I checked the code in detail to make sure that I don't have such things and I am confident that I don't have it. so use namespace boost in my code.

Answer (score 0):

that's happening because you include all threading library

```
 #include <boost/thread.hpp> // includes mutex, thread_time, tss and lot's of stuff
```

If you need threads only include only that file.

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
```